# How can I make one button toggle other buttons in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to optimize my code, I completely don't know what can I do with it to make it shorter and cleaner.
What can I do to make this code cleaner and shorter?
I would appreciate tips about making and having code being clean

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#artButton").click(function()
    {
    $("#dlc").fadeIn(500); 
    $("#info").fadeOut(500); 
    $("#info").fadeOut(500);
    $("#info").fadeOut(500);
    }),
    $("#infoButton").click(function()
    {
        $("#dlc").fadeOut(500);
        $("#info").fadeIn(500);
        $("#placeholder").fadeOut(500);
        $("#placeholder").fadeOut(500);        
    }),
    $("#placeholderButton").click(function()
    {
        $("#dlc").fadeOut(500);
        $("#info").fadeOut(500);
        $("#placeholder").fadeIn(500);
        $("#placeholder").fadeOut(500); 
    }),
    $("#placeholderButton2").click(function()
    {
        $("#dlc").fadeOut(500);
        $("#info").fadeOut(500);
        $("#placeholder").fadeOut(500);
        $("#placeholder").fadeIn(500); 
    });
});
```

Comment: why use ` $("#info").fadeOut(500); ` 3 times in `$("#artButton").click` ? or `$("#placeholder").fadeOut(500);` , `$("#placeholder").fadeIn(500);` in the same `$("#placeholderButton2").click()` ?

Comment: I just had 4 buttons and I wanted to place all of them in my code, that way I could change Id, class later on when I needed to

Comment: this is not a good way to proceed. There are certainly better things to do for this kind of code, for example having an array on objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some respects it's a matter of opinion, but one thing you could do is combine rules with identical events, remove duplicate events, and chain events that happen on the same element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#artButton").click(function() {
      $("#dlc").fadeIn(500);
      $("#info").fadeOut(500);
    }),
    $("#infoButton").click(function() {
      $("#dlc").fadeOut(500);
      $("#info").fadeIn(500);
      $("#placeholder").fadeOut(500);
    }),
    $("#placeholderButton").click(function() {
      $("#dlc", "#info").fadeOut(500);
      $("#placeholder").fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);
    }),
    $("#placeholderButton2").click(function() {
      $("#dlc", "#info").fadeOut(500);
      $("#placeholder").fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="artButton">artButton</button><button id="infoButton">infoButton</button><button id="placeholderButton">placeholderButton</button><button id="placeholderButton2">placeholderButton2</button>

<hr>
<div id="dlc">dlc</div>
<div id="info">info</div>
<div id="placeholder">placeholder</div>
```